# Issues with java reinstallation

Tags: java

I first installed java in `Program files(*86)` and Rstudio(R version 3.4.3) in `Program files` folder. This did not work. Then I tried to copy the java files to program files folder and update the environment variables and still it did not work.

I wanted to run the Rjava package which did not run. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot combine 32-bit and 64-bit applications.**

- Your Rstudio is 64-bits (which explains why the installer wants to us `Program Files`.
- Your Java Installation is 32-bits (Installer wants to use `Program Files (x86)` folder.

To get it working, first uninstall java. Then reinstall java in 64-bits.

You can get the correct version from Oracle: https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp (Chose `Windows Offline (64-bit)`).